# Closing a SocketChannel retrieved by ServerSocketChannel.accept()

Tags: java

I have a timer on daemon thread which is continuously writing data into a [`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html). In the main class I do not have the object reference of this socket channel, but I do have the reference of the [`ServerSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) to which this socket channel is connected. So I do this to close the channel.

```
socketChannel = serverSocket.accept();
socketChannel.close();
```

But there is a latency involved in the deamon thread's socket channel close. Though they both refer to the same socket channel, the timer task writes into this socket channel even after the above `close()` is invoked until a few milliseconds.

Kindly suggest how to ensure the close is made completed. This is an non blocking channel.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense. That code doesn't 'refer to the same socket channel' at all, and it therefore doesn't close it: it accepts a new one and closes that, which also doesn't make sense, at least not to the client who made that new connection and is probably expecting some service on it, not an immediate close.

You just need to arrange to have the reference to the existing channel available to the code that needs to close it. This is Programming 101, hardly a networking question at all.

Comment: Hi, Appreciate the way you called it a 101 but can you validate your statement, do you say object returned by serversocketchannel.accept() is a new channel? Then could you justify where the connection of that client takes place?

Comment: @user915534 Yes. The SocketChannel returned by accept() is a new incoming connection from a client. That is where the incoming connection is formed. Your code creates two SocketChannels: one from accept(), which is the incoming connection from the client, and one from SocketChannel.open(), which is a connection from the server to itself. They are different.

Answer (score 0):

You need synchronization. Share some object between these threads. Then you can do something like this:
main thread:

```
synchronized(object){
    socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept()
    socketChannel.close(). 
}
```

daemon thread:

```
synchronized(object){
    timerTask.write(socketChannel, data)
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point here, why should they be synchronized? I'm closing the right socket channel but the point is that the socket gets closed after a few milliseconds in the daemon thread which is incorrect.

Comment: If something in one thread happens at slightly different moment than it is needed by another thread then I would try to synchronize things. Why don't you try it? Are you sure that you measured the moments correctly?